# What happens when invalid amp page is cached in the google cache and open the cache url

Tags: amp-html

let my page URL be www.xyz.com.
when I cache this URL, Google generates a cached URL like **https://www-xyz-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/www.xyz.com**.

If the **www.xyz.com** is invalid amp page(i.e., it has an amp validation error) and if I clicked on the cached URL (**https://www-xyz-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/www.xyz.com** ) it will redirect to the actual URL (**www.xyz.com**) instead of serving from the cache.

In this case, since Google is unable to serve the page from the cache, do we get 404 errors or any other errors? If yes, how do we monitor the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of guidelines when it comes to invalidating AMP cache URL's, the details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/remove-amp). If your document was previously valid but is *no longer* valid, the AMP cache will continue to serve the most recent valid version unless you intervene.

To answer your second question can monitor AMP validation errors in the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about), there's a tab specifically for AMP that allows you to view errors that are occurring in production.